# How to create-edit-remove excel files?

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++

i am doing a project that has some simple values(login,password,name,age). I was searching on the internet how to create an excel file on Visual C++, and i cant undestand it . I just want the simple way, i just want to see on my excel files 2 colums one having some login codes of my program and on the other the passwords. My programing level its not really high and im not an english speaker, so id like you guys to explain a bit or give me something simple.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a simple file with 2 columns of data, I'd make a CSV (Comma Seperated Values) file, which can be opened in Excel, or any text editor. The CSV will look "nice" in Excel, as if it were an actual XLS file. Also, you won't be tied to Microsoft Office. This file can be written with simple string manipulations and file I/O.

The format would be :

```
Column1,Column2
data1,data2
data3,data4
```

However, and this is a big one... storing usernames and passwords in plain text is **never** a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some code from this web site that can help you out.  It seems well documented and it was made for people to learn from it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15837/Accessing-Excel-Spreadsheets-via-C

Hope that helps!